# C# Unity2: Problem resolving genrics when using a lifetimemanager

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, unity-container, lifetime

I am using ASP MVC 3 (RC) with Unity 2 with great success. However, I have one problem that I cannot wrap my head around. Behind the scenes I use POCO (Person, Company, ...) which I access through repositories. The repositories are made as generics (EFRepository), and use a context. Without LifetimeManager on the generic repository type everything works as expected:

```
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container
            .RegisterType<ObjectContext, DataLayerContext>(
                new HttpRequestLifetimeManager<ObjectContext>())
            .RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EFRepository<>))

        //Works
        var unitOfWork = (IUnitOfWork)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>());
        //Works
        var webPersonRepository = (IRepository<WebPerson>)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRepository<WebPerson>>();
```

However, when adding the LifetimeManager to the repository as well, the resolving fails:

```
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container
            .RegisterType<ObjectContext, DataLayerContext>(
                new HttpRequestLifetimeManager<ObjectContext>())
            .RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EFRepository<>),
                new HttpRequestLifetimeManager(typeof(IRepository<>)))

        //Works
        var unitOfWork = (IUnitOfWork)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>());
        //Does NOT work anymore!
        var webPersonRepository = (IRepository<WebPerson>)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRepository<WebPerson>>();
```

Any ideas? The implementation of the HttpRequestLifetimeManager is very standard:

```
public class HttpRequestLifetimeManager<T> : HttpRequestLifetimeManager
{
    public HttpRequestLifetimeManager() : base(typeof(T))
    {

    }
}

public class HttpRequestLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager, IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _key;

    public HttpRequestLifetimeManager(Type T)
    {
        _key = @"HttpRequestContextLifetimeManager" + T.Name;
    }

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Items[_key];
    }

    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(_key);
    }
    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[_key] = newValue;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        RemoveValue();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
/Victor

Comment: "Does NOT work anymore!" means it throws an exception? Wich one? Can you post the messages of the exception chain?

Comment: Well, since that is the idea by design it returns null. Basically it means that it cannot initiate the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone wants to know, the reason was that the custom LifetimeManager I used used a type as input (either using generics or as a constructor argument). When using the LifetimeManager on a generic type that will fail, so dont do that :)

In the end we decided to use {string}+Guid.NewGuid() as the key.

/Victor